# Publishing articles to different Sites

Tags: publishing-site

I am planning a SharePoint 2010 solution with an intranet / extranet and internet site.

The intranet and extranet will probably use different authentication methods. The internet site will probably be in a different domain (DMZ domain)

How can I publish an article on one site, and then have it published to the other sites? Is there a way to do this in SharePoint, or should I for example use Biztalk between the sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to roll your own solution for this. Despite this being a feature of other CMS systems and even being something that was in Content Management Server 2002 way back when, SharePoint is not really designed to share content across site collection boundaries.

Obviously SharePoint has a variety of integration platform features which could facilitate such a solution, such as the web services.

You *might* be able to concoct something with the BCS, but that would depend on either the SQL server being somewhere somehow accessible inside and outside the DMZ (!) or replication of some sort.